# How to change language in specific page using Joomla

Tags: redirect, multilingual, joomla-3.9

Currently, I am creating multi-language pages with several type of languages.

My home page is set for English. When I try to change the language from the second/third page, the others language will redirect me to the index page of each language and not at the particular page I want.

p/s: I am using Joomla version, 3.9.22.

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement associations - the guide for this can be found in the Joomla documentation - [Multilingual Associations](https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Multilingual_Associations#).

Comment: Please edit your answer to offer more than a link-only answer.  The system flags these as low-quality based on the length/quality.  If you need more detail from the OP to give a better answer, please seek more details from the OP.